# Raising an array to different values

Tags: python

I'm planning on plotting  y^n vs x for different values of n. Here is my sample code:

```
import numpy as np

x=np.range(1,5)
y=np.range(2,9,2)

exponent=np.linspace(1,8,50)

z=y**exponent
```

With this, I got the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4) (5)
```

My idea is that for each value of n, I will get an array where that array contains the new values of y that is now raised to n. For instance:

```
y1= [] #an array where y**1
y2= [] #an array where y**1.5
y3= [] #an array where y**2
```

etc. I don't know if how I can get that 50 arrays for y**n and is there an easier way to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "broadcasting" (explained [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) in the docs) and create a new axis:

```
z = y**exponent[:,np.newaxis]
```

In other words, instead of

```
>>> y = np.arange(2,9,2)
>>> exponent = np.linspace(1, 8, 50)
>>> z = y**exponent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-40-2fe7ff9626ed>", line 1, in <module>
    z = y**exponent
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (50,)
```

You can use `array[:,np.newaxis]` (or `array[:,None]`, the same thing, but `newaxis` is more explicit about your intent) to give the array an extra dimension of size 1:

```
>>> exponent.shape
(50,)
>>> exponent[:,np.newaxis].shape
(50, 1)
```

and so

```
>>> z = y**exponent[:,np.newaxis]
>>> z.shape
(50, 4)
>>> z[0]
array([ 2.,  4.,  6.,  8.])
>>> z[1]
array([  2.20817903,   4.87605462,   7.75025005,  10.76720154])
>>> z[0]**exponent[1]
array([  2.20817903,   4.87605462,   7.75025005,  10.76720154])
```